# No power steering.

Tags: power-steering

I have a 97 CRV that has a bad leak in the power steering on the rack and pinion. I have taken the belt off the pump. How long can I drive it this way?

Comment: Not long really especially if the leak is bad - that power steering fluid also lubricates the rack and pinion , best get it sorted properly : safety is also a concern.

Comment: It really only leaks when it has pressure and it is only a 900 do

Comment: Ouch. That happened to me once. I broke the power steering fan belt adjustment system. Bolt snapped clean off. Mine didn't leak, but didn't provide any power steering assist either. I drove that car for over 10,000 miles without the power steering belt. I'm sure I didn't do the system any good, but the car drove just fine.

Answer (score 1):

not very long, the rack and pinon needs to be lubed up on the inside also. If there is no oil, the gears will grind together.

Answer (score 1):

Not long really, especially if the leak is bad - that power steering fluid also lubricates the rack and pinion , best get it sorted properly : safety is also a concern.

It's not the size of the engine, it's the job the component does...